# Activation function used for mlpML in Caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, activation-function, mlp

I am using the Caret package in R, trying to implement multi-layer perceptron for classifying satellite images. I am using `method=mlpML`, and I would like to know which activation function is being used.

Here is my code:

```
controlparameters<-trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                               number=5,
                               repeats = 5,
                               savePredictions=TRUE,
                                classProbs = TRUE)
mlp_grid<-expand.grid(layer1=13,
                      layer2=0,
                      layer3=0)
model< train(as.factor(Species)~.,
                   data = smotedata,
                   method='mlpML',
                   preProc =  c('center', 'scale'),
                   trcontrol=controlparameters,
                   tuneGrid=mlp_grid,
                   importance=T)
```

I used a single layer since it performed the best than using multi-layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the caret source code for [`mlpML`](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/mlpML.R), it turns out that it uses the `mlp` function of the [RSNNS package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/index.html).

According to the [RSNNS `mlp` documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/RSNNS/man/mlp.html), its default arguments are:

```
mlp(x, ...)

## Default S3 method:
mlp(x, y, size = c(5), maxit = 100,
  initFunc = "Randomize_Weights", initFuncParams = c(-0.3, 0.3),
  learnFunc = "Std_Backpropagation", learnFuncParams = c(0.2, 0),
  updateFunc = "Topological_Order", updateFuncParams = c(0),
  hiddenActFunc = "Act_Logistic", shufflePatterns = TRUE,
  linOut = FALSE, outputActFunc = if (linOut) "Act_Identity" else
  "Act_Logistic", inputsTest = NULL, targetsTest = NULL,
  pruneFunc = NULL, pruneFuncParams = NULL, ...)
```

from which it is apparent that `hiddenActFunc = "Act_Logistic"`, i.e the activation function for the hidden layers, is the logistic one.